# Is it possible to add multiple element in one go in Gstreamer using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer

I am looking for python3 equivalent of the following

```
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, sink, NULL);
```

Currently I am able to do the following and it works fine.

```
    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline.new("test-pipeline")
    pipeline.add(source)
    pipeline.add(sink)`
```

Comment: I think the closes thing you can do is use `for` loop to add elements. `for element in [source, sink]: pipeline.add(element)`